# How to convert CSV data to JSON object in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to get CSV data from local file and convert it into JSON object(IOS and android). Is there any plugin available that can convert a CSV file to JSON in react-native

Answer (score 2):

You should be fine using [papaparse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse).

Install it via `npm`.

```sh
npm install papaparse
```

Parse a CSV string to json as follows.

```js
import PapaParse from 'papaparse'

options = {} // dummy options
PapaParse.parse(str, options);
```

The variable `str` contains the CSV. The return value is a JSON object.

There exists a convenient wrapper around papaparse for react native called [react-native-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-csv), but it doesn’t seem to be updated frequently.